# Finding Number of Customers Who Played at Least One Product Video

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I am looking through the progression of pages users clicked on within one of our apps. Customers can go backwards in the process and each action has a time stamp. I want to find the percentage of customers who played a protection plan video at least once

ActivityType: page title (can visit the same page more than once)
Interested in "Products Presented" (Main protection plan page) and "Product Video Viewed"
ConsumerID: customers unique identifier
EventDateTime: Timestamp for each page visit

Is there a way to count CustomerId that played at least one video?

```
DistinctCustomersPlayedVideo = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(ConsumerFunnelTime[ConsumerID],
    COUNT(ConsumerFunnelTime[ActivityType] IN {"ProductVideoViewed"} >= 1))
)
```

I can then divide this by the number of distinct customers that made it to the protection page at least once

Data:
{
EventDateTime   ActivityType    ConsumerID  ConsumerFunnel
22:48.0 Products Presented  4623439 1
22:50.0 Products Presented  4623439 2
26:15.0 Product Video Viewed    4623439 3
44:27.0 Products Presented  4673980 1
44:27.0 Products Presented  4673980 1
29:10.0 Products Presented  4674538 1
29:11.0 Products Presented  4674538 2
11:50.0 Products Presented  4674699 1
11:50.0 Products Presented  4674699 1
21:02.0 Products Presented  4674721 1
21:03.0 Products Presented  4674721 2
52:17.0 Products Presented  4674837 1
52:19.0 Products Presented  4674837 2
26:16.0 Products Presented  4674837 3
26:18.0 Products Presented  4674837 4
}

Comment: Where's the sample data?

Comment: @Peter what is the best way to share sample data for Power BI?

Comment: @Peter can you import that into excel as a text file delimited by spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this measure:

```
DistinctCustomersPlayedVideo = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(ConsumerFunnelTime[ConsumerID]),
    ConsumerFunnelTime[ActivityType] = "Product Video Viewed"
)
```